# How to set a new property using the "set" method

Tags: javascript

I want to set the weapon with "setWeapon" by creating the "weapon" property  too. Example call: "archer.setWeapon (bow);"

```js
 function Weapon(name,damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }
    Weapon.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.name + this.damage + " damage"; // method to show weapon
    };
    var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20); // create weapon 
    function Character() {
        this.health = 100;
        this.basicDamage = 10;
        this.toString = function () {
            return this.name + this.type; // add and show weapon bow
        };
    Character.createArcher = function () { // create hero 
        var hero = new Character;
        hero.name = "Legolas";
        return hero;
    };
    Character.setWeapon = function () { 
        var weapon = new Character();
        weapon.type = Weapon;
        return weapon;
    };
    var archer = new Character.createArcher();
    archer.setWeapon(bow); // set the selected weapon
    console.log(archer.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extend prototype of Character with setWeapon and setters just sets the value - they don't return values. You can write getWeapon() for that. This way you pass actual weapon and assign to the archer. Hope that helps. (Weapon is an object so you can access archer.weapon.type)

```
var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20); // create weapon 

Character.prototype.setWeapon = function (weapon) { 
    var me = this;
    me.weapon = weapon; // set the weapon
};

var archer = new Character.createArcher();
archer.setWeapon(bow); // set the selected weapon
console.log(archer.toString()); // add to string also property weapon
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: archer.setWeapon is not a function : (